# Angular formatting date within Ternary Operator in Template Binding

Tags: angularjs

I want to show blank for a null date or a formatted date if not null.

```
<td>{{item.CompletedDate ? item.CompletedDate | moment : 'lll' : ''}}</td>
```

The above obviously doesn't work because of the `:` character.

Simply not formatting the date as below works, but I need the date formatted.

```
<td>{{item.CompletedDate ? item.CompletedDate : ''}}</td>
```

Is there a way to escape the result or a better way to handle the null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try (I assumed `moment` is a defined filter):

```
<td>{{item.CompletedDate ? (item.CompletedDate | moment : 'lll') : ''}}</td>
```

Comment: So simple thank you! Can't believe I didn't try that. Tried different brackets :S